# move content from a folder with unknown name up one directory

Tags: files, mv

I have data arranged as follows:

```
--parent_dir
   |
   --4Bz27go1c
      |
      -- foo.md
      -- bar.tar.gz
      -- baz.c
      ..
```

I have a parent directory with a known name and a child directory with an unknown name (represented here as `4Bz27go1c`. How can I copy all the contents from inside the child directory and move it up to inside the parent directory and also delete the now empty child directory?

To be clear, the final result that I'm describing should look like this:

```
 --parent_dir
    |
    -- foo.md
    -- bar.tar.gz
    -- baz.c
    ..
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are in the child then:
Using bash shell,

```
shopt -s dotglob
mv -t .. *
rmdir $(pwd)
```

If your `mv` does not have `-t` then:

```
shopt -s dotglob
mv * ..
rmdir $(pwd)
```

Comment: `rmdir .` won't work. `-t` implies GNU `mv`.

Comment: `rmdir .` produces an error: `Invalid argument`.

Comment: Updated to not need `-t`. And strangely `rmdir .` does not work, don't know why. However `rmdir $(pwd)` does.

Answer (score 0):

```
cd parent_dir &&
  set -- */ &&
  for dir do
    [ -L "$dir" ] && continue
    mv -i -- "$dir"* "$dir"..?* "$dir".[!.]*
    rmdir -- "$dir"
  done
```